# iOS 5/6: low volume after first usage of CoreAudio

Tags: ios, core-audio, voip, volume

I work on a VoIP app. The AudioSession's mode is set to kAudioSessionMode_VoiceChat.

For a call, I open a CoreAudio AudioUnit with subtype kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO . Everything works fine. After the first call, I close the AudioUnit with AudioUnitUninitialize() and I deactivate the audio session.

Now, however, it seems as if the audio device is not correctly released: the ringer volume is very low, the media player's volume is lower than usual. And for a subsequent call, I cannot activate kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO anymore. It works to create an AudioUnit with kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO instead, but also the call's volume is very low (both receiver and speaker).

This first occured on iOS 5. With the iPhone 5 on iOS 6, it is even worse (even lower volume).

Has anyone seen this? Do I need to do more than AudioUnitUninitialize() to release the Voice Processing unit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution: I've incorrectly used `AudioUnitUninitialize()` to free the audio component retrieved with `AudioComponentInstanceNew()`. Correct is to use `AudioComponentInstanceDispose()`.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. For me I'm switching between vpio and remoteio. I tried as you suggested, using AudioComponentInstanceDispose() but after doing so and retrieving a new copy I cannot setProperty on the instance anymore. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: on VPIO, even after using AudioComponentInstanceDispose(), the volume still lowers, anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to dispose the audioUnit when using voiceProcessingIO. For some reason there is no problem when using RemoteIO subtype. So whenever you get OSStatus -66635 (kAudioQueueErr_MultipleVoiceProcessors), check for missing AudioComponentInstanceDispose() calls.

Comment: Hi MrJ, may I ask where you found the OSStatus -66635's definition? Thank you very much.

Comment: I contacted the apple dev support about this issue and they've send me the definition (besides other information). I'm not sure if you could find that on your own .. i did not :)

PS: for your other question (i cannot comment on others answers yet): i re-initialize the autdio unit completely new with `AudioComponentInstanceNew`, after dispoing it. It's pretty fast if there are no buffered data waiting to be played (i zap them before disposal).